# Rolagem automática para o áudio em execução em uma playllist

Tags: javascript, html5

No seguinte player o áudio em execução não é mostrado, ou seja, se estiver tocando o áudio 10 a página não rola até o mesmo, como fazer uma rolagem automática para que, a página seja rolado até o áudio em execução?

```js
// Dependencies:
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/2.0.18/plyr.js

// Inspiration: http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio
// Mythium Archive: https://archive.org/details/mythium/


jQuery(function ($) {
    'use strict'
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 3,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "5:01",
                "file": "BS_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 4,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "8:31",
                "file": "BSFM_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 5,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "BSFM_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 6,
                "name": "All This Is - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "AC_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 7,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 1) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:44",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 8,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 2) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:26",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 9,
                "name": "Magus - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "AC_M"
            }, {
                "track": 10,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address (fucked up) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:25",
                "file": "AC_TSOWAfucked_up"
            }, {
                "track": 11,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "5:53",
                "file": "PNY04-05_M"
            }, {
                "track": 12,
                "name": "On The Waterfront - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "4:40",
                "file": "PNY04-05_OTW"
            }, {
                "track": 13,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "13:15",
                "file": "PNY04-05_T"
            }, {
                "track": 14,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "8:12",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 15,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "7:02",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 16,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:43",
                "file": "PVD_M"
            }, {
                "track": 17,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "10:45",
                "file": "PVD_T"
            }, {
                "track": 18,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:36",
                "file": "PVD_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 19,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 20,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_M"
            }, {
                "track": 21,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "13:07",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_BTPE"
            }, {
                "track": 22,
                "name": "Innocence - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:16",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_I"
            }, {
                "track": 23,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 24,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "4:51",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 25,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "8:43",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 26,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "3:00",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 27,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "6:09",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 28,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 29,
                "name": "Trance - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "12:32",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_T"
            }, {
                "track": 30,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "8:56",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 31,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "4:55",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 32,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "5:45",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 33,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "14:05",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 34,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "13:25",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 35,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:37",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 36,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:36",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_2"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $(tracks).each(function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li><div class="plItem"><span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span><span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span><span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span></div></li>');
            }),
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).on('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).on('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
    }
});

// initialize plyr
plyr.setup($('#audio1'), {});
```

```css
/* Font Family
================================================== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700');


/* Global Styles
================================================== */

html,body {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
background-color:#0665a2;
color:#fff;
font-size:105%;
font-family:"Oxygen", HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
letter-spacing:.025rem;
line-height:1.618;
padding:1rem 0;
}

* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}


/* Setup
================================================== */

.container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; width:100%; }
.column { width:inherit; }


/* Typography / Links
================================================== */

p { color:#fff; display:block; font-size:.9rem; font-weight:400; margin:0 0 2px; }

a,a:visited { color:#8cc3e6; outline:0; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover,a:focus { color:#bbdef5; }
p a,p a:visited { line-height:inherit; }


/* Misc.
================================================== */

.add-bottom { margin-bottom:2rem !important; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.center { text-align:center; }


/* Audio Player Styles
================================================== */

audio {
margin:0 15px 0 14px;
width:670px;
}

#mainwrap {}

#audiowrap,
#plwrap {
margin:0 auto;
}

#tracks {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#nowPlay {
display:inline;
}

#npAction {
padding:21px;
position:absolute;
}

#npTitle {
padding:21px;
}

#plList li {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:21px 0;
}

#plList li:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plItem {
position:relative;
}

.plTitle {
left:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:65px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
top:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.plNum {
padding-left:21px;
width:25px;
}

.plLength {
padding-left:21px;
position:absolute;
right:21px;
top:0;
}

.plSel,
.plSel:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
cursor:default !important;
}

a[id^="btn"] {
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:2rem;
height:35px;
line-height:.8;
margin:0 20px 20px;
padding:5px 10px;
text-decoration:none;
transition:background .3s ease;
width:35px;
}

a[id^="btn"]:last-child {
margin-left:-4px;
}

a[id^="btn"]:hover,
a[id^="btn"]:active {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
}

a[id^="btn"]::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
padding:0;
}


/* Plyr Overrides
================================================== */

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls {
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 20px 20px 13px;
width:100%;
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button.tab-focus:focus,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button:hover,
.plyr__play-large {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr__progress--played, .plyr__volume--display {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer,
.plyr--audio .plyr__volume--display {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


/* Media Queries
================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width:850px) {
    #nowPlay { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/2.0.18/plyr.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.plyr.io/2.0.13/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column add-bottom">
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="nowPlay">
                <span class="left" id="npAction">Paused...</span>
                <span class="right" id="npTitle"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="audiowrap">
                <div id="audio0">
                    <audio preload id="audio1" controls="controls">Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio!</audio>
                </div>
                <div id="tracks">
                    <a id="btnPrev">&larr;</a>
                    <a id="btnNext">&rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="plwrap">
                <ul id="plList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column add-bottom center">
        <p>Music by <a href="http://www.mythium.net/">Mythium</a></p>
        <p>Download: <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_vbr_mp3.zip">zip</a> / <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_archive.torrent">torrent</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, descreva o problema.

Comment: Adicionado a descrição @dvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `animate` do jQuery dentro da função `loadTrack = function (id) {...}`:

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".plSel").offset().top}
);
```

Isso irá rolar a tela até o elemento com a classe `.plSel`, que é a música que está tocando.

```js
// Dependencies:
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/2.0.18/plyr.js

// Inspiration: http://jonhall.info/how_to/create_a_playlist_for_html5_audio
// Mythium Archive: https://archive.org/details/mythium/


jQuery(function ($) {
    'use strict'
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 3,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "5:01",
                "file": "BS_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 4,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "8:31",
                "file": "BSFM_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 5,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "BSFM_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 6,
                "name": "All This Is - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "AC_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 7,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 1) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:44",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 8,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 2) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:26",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 9,
                "name": "Magus - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "AC_M"
            }, {
                "track": 10,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address (fucked up) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:25",
                "file": "AC_TSOWAfucked_up"
            }, {
                "track": 11,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "5:53",
                "file": "PNY04-05_M"
            }, {
                "track": 12,
                "name": "On The Waterfront - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "4:40",
                "file": "PNY04-05_OTW"
            }, {
                "track": 13,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "13:15",
                "file": "PNY04-05_T"
            }, {
                "track": 14,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "8:12",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 15,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "7:02",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 16,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:43",
                "file": "PVD_M"
            }, {
                "track": 17,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "10:45",
                "file": "PVD_T"
            }, {
                "track": 18,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:36",
                "file": "PVD_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 19,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 20,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_M"
            }, {
                "track": 21,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "13:07",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_BTPE"
            }, {
                "track": 22,
                "name": "Innocence - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:16",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_I"
            }, {
                "track": 23,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 24,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "4:51",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 25,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "8:43",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 26,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "3:00",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 27,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "6:09",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 28,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 29,
                "name": "Trance - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "12:32",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_T"
            }, {
                "track": 30,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "8:56",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 31,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "4:55",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 32,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "5:45",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 33,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "14:05",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 34,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "13:25",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 35,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:37",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 36,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:36",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_2"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $(tracks).each(function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li><div class="plItem"><span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span><span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span><span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span></div></li>');
            }),
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).on('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).on('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');

                // ANIMATE
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".plSel").offset().top
                });

                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
    }
});

// initialize plyr
plyr.setup($('#audio1'), {});
```

```css
/* Font Family
================================================== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700');


/* Global Styles
================================================== */

html,body {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
background-color:#0665a2;
color:#fff;
font-size:105%;
font-family:"Oxygen", HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
letter-spacing:.025rem;
line-height:1.618;
padding:1rem 0;
}

* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}


/* Setup
================================================== */

.container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; width:100%; }
.column { width:inherit; }


/* Typography / Links
================================================== */

p { color:#fff; display:block; font-size:.9rem; font-weight:400; margin:0 0 2px; }

a,a:visited { color:#8cc3e6; outline:0; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover,a:focus { color:#bbdef5; }
p a,p a:visited { line-height:inherit; }


/* Misc.
================================================== */

.add-bottom { margin-bottom:2rem !important; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.center { text-align:center; }


/* Audio Player Styles
================================================== */

audio {
margin:0 15px 0 14px;
width:670px;
}

#mainwrap {}

#audiowrap,
#plwrap {
margin:0 auto;
}

#tracks {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#nowPlay {
display:inline;
}

#npAction {
padding:21px;
position:absolute;
}

#npTitle {
padding:21px;
}

#plList li {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:21px 0;
}

#plList li:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plItem {
position:relative;
}

.plTitle {
left:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:65px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
top:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.plNum {
padding-left:21px;
width:25px;
}

.plLength {
padding-left:21px;
position:absolute;
right:21px;
top:0;
}

.plSel,
.plSel:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
cursor:default !important;
}

a[id^="btn"] {
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:2rem;
height:35px;
line-height:.8;
margin:0 20px 20px;
padding:5px 10px;
text-decoration:none;
transition:background .3s ease;
width:35px;
}

a[id^="btn"]:last-child {
margin-left:-4px;
}

a[id^="btn"]:hover,
a[id^="btn"]:active {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
}

a[id^="btn"]::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
padding:0;
}


/* Plyr Overrides
================================================== */

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls {
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 20px 20px 13px;
width:100%;
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button.tab-focus:focus,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button:hover,
.plyr__play-large {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr__progress--played, .plyr__volume--display {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer,
.plyr--audio .plyr__volume--display {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


/* Media Queries
================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width:850px) {
    #nowPlay { display:none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/2.0.18/plyr.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.plyr.io/2.0.13/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column add-bottom">
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="nowPlay">
                <span class="left" id="npAction">Paused...</span>
                <span class="right" id="npTitle"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="audiowrap">
                <div id="audio0">
                    <audio preload id="audio1" controls="controls">Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio!</audio>
                </div>
                <div id="tracks">
                    <a id="btnPrev">&larr;</a>
                    <a id="btnNext">&rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="plwrap">
                <ul id="plList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column add-bottom center">
        <p>Music by <a href="http://www.mythium.net/">Mythium</a></p>
        <p>Download: <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_vbr_mp3.zip">zip</a> / <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_archive.torrent">torrent</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou @dvd, como faço pra colocar uma margem superior, ao invés de rolar para o topo? pois eu fixei o tocador. como nesse exemplo:
http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=hinosSalmosCanticos#0

Comment: Não consegui fixar o tocador em minha pergunta

Comment: Vc pode subtrair um valor, tipo: `scrollTop: $(".plSel").offset().top-50`

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. Cara muito obrigado!